# WIMMountImageHandle results in ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: c#, .net, api

I'm writing a program analyzing [MSWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format) [files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd799284(v=ws.10)).

Minimal Example:

```
    static void Test()
    {
        UIntPtr creationResult = UIntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr WIMHandle = WIM.WIMCreateFile(@"D:\ISOCpy\install.wim", (uint)WIM.CreateFileAccess.Mount, (uint)WIM.CreateFileMode.OpenExisting, 0, 0, out creationResult);
        if (WIMHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not open WIM File. LastError: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() + " / 0x" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString("x"));
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // Set TMP Path
            if (!WIM.WIMSetTemporaryPath(WIMHandle, @"D:\ISOCpy\y"))
            {
                // handle will be closed in destructor
                Console.WriteLine("Could not set WIM temp path. LastError: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() + " / 0x" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString("x"));
                return;
            }

            int imgnums = WIM.WIMGetImageCount(WIMHandle);
            if (imgnums <= 0)
            {
                // handle will be closed in destructor
                Console.WriteLine("Could not get number of WIMimages. Return: " + imgnums + "; LastError: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() + " / 0x" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString("x"));
                return;
            }

            for (uint mountindex = 1; mountindex <= imgnums; mountindex++)
            {
                String mountpath = @"D:\ISOCpy\z_" + mountindex;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(mountpath);

                IntPtr ImgHandle = WIM.WIMLoadImage(WIMHandle, mountindex);
                if (ImgHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    int rc = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Utils.DeleteDir(mountpath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not WIMLoadImage. Image: " + mountindex + "; LastError: " + rc + " / 0x" + rc.ToString("x"));
                    return;
                }
                if (!WIM.WIMMountImageHandle(ImgHandle, mountpath, 0))
                {
                    int rc = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    Utils.DeleteDir(mountpath);
                    Console.WriteLine("Could not WIMMountImageHandle. Image: " + mountindex + "; LastError: " + rc + " / 0x" + rc.ToString("x"));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            //WIM.WIMCloseHandle(WIMHandle); TODO
        }
    }
```

But [WIMMountImageHandle](http://systemscenter.ru/wimgapi.en/html/f00ba235-e0d9-4061-926c-211cda982834.htm) did not work. It always failed with error 6:[ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). I did not see anything in the [documentation](http://systemscenter.ru/wimgapi.en/html/f00ba235-e0d9-4061-926c-211cda982834.htm)

WIMMountImage will work, but I need the attributes provided by WIMMountImageHandle.

Answer (score 0):

At least, I got it..

The file has to be opened with additional "read" access:

```
IntPtr WIMHandle = WIM.WIMCreateFile(@"D:\ISOCpy\install.wim", 
    ((uint)WIM.CreateFileAccess.Mount | (uint)WIM.CreateFileAccess.Read), 
    (uint)WIM.CreateFileMode.OpenExisting, 0, 0, out creationResult);
```